# how do i fix the error in a terraform file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

aws_cloudformation_stack fails to update on parameters change while using terraform

I am trying to create a dynamodb using terraform. I have a file which is in yaml, we have converted the file to JSON and used it but we get a lot of errors. I followed this link

`https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudformation_stack.html`

the first part when i use the vpc it gives me the error and i have remove it as and when i keep removing them i keep getting new erros .. so i came across a command tf_terraform plan and i looked for the warn
the below is the snippet

```
2019/03/31 11:55:08 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider.aws (close)", waiting for: "aws_cloudformation_stack.dynamodb" 2019/03/31 11:55:08 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root", waiting for: "meta.count-boundary (count boundary fixup)" 2019/03/31 11:55:08 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "meta.count-boundary (count boundary fixup)", waiting for: "aws_cloudformation_stack.dynamodb" 2019/03/31 11:55:13 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "aws_cloudformation_stack.dynamodb", waiting for: "provider.aws" 2019/03/31 11:55:13 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root", waiting for: "meta.count-boundary (count boundary fixup)" 2019/03/31 11:55:13 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider.aws (close)", waiting for: "aws_cloudformation_stack.dynamodb" 2019/03/31 11:55:13 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "meta.count-boundary (count boundary fixup)", waiting for: "aws_cloudformation_stack.dynamodb"
```

it keeps on going what am i doing wrong and is this a bug i have attached tfplan file

my code is like this

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "network" {
name = "networking-stack"
template_body = <<STACK
{
"Parameters": {
"ParamReadCapacityUnitsDynamoDB": {
"Description": "ReadCapacityUnits",
"Type": "Number",
"MinValue": 1,
"MaxValue": 5,
"Default": 1
},
"ParamWriteCapacityUnitsDynamoDB": {
"Description": "WriteCapacityUnits",
"Type": "Number",
"MinValue": 1,
"MaxValue": 5,
"Default": 1
}
},
"Resources": {
"DynamoDB": {
"Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
"Properties": {
"TableName": "Name",
"AttributeDefinitions": [
{
"AttributeName": "PartitionKey",
"AttributeType": "S"
},
{
"AttributeName": "SortKey",
"AttributeType": "S"
}
],
"KeySchema": [
{
"AttributeName": "PartitionKey",
"KeyType": "HASH"
},
{
"AttributeName": "SortKey",
"KeyType": "RANGE"
}
],
"ProvisionedThroughput": {
"ReadCapacityUnits": 20,
"WriteCapacityUnits": 20
},
"GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
{
"IndexName": "userGSI",
"KeySchema": [
{
"AttributeName": "SortKey",
"KeyType": "HASH"
},
{
"AttributeName": "PartitionKey",
"KeyType": "RANGE"
}
],
"Projection": {
"ProjectionType": "ALL"
},
"ProvisionedThroughput": {
"ReadCapacityUnits": 20,
"WriteCapacityUnits": 20
}
}
],
"StreamSpecification": {
"StreamViewType": "NEW_IMAGE"
},
"Tags": [
{
"Key": "System",
"Value": dynamodb
}
]
}
}
}
}
STACK
}
```

I expect to create the dynamo db file from the json file embeded

Comment: Why are you using CloudFormation here rather than using the DynamoDB resource directly? The CloyeFormation resource is to be used as an escape hatch when on the rare occasions CloudFormation implements a feature before Terraform's AWS provider does.

Comment: @vdaetskcoR thank you so muc for clearing that out.. can you give me any example or any link where i could look at it ,. I am very new to this

Answer (score 0):

Look at using the DynamoDB table resource directly, as opposed to using a CloudFormation stack in Terraform.

Samples/docs:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/dynamodb_table.html
https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-dynamodb/tree/master/examples/complete